Git blame API for bitbucket
On receiving bitbucket pull request webhook event I want to find who previously made the change in line which is being change in this new pull request. One idea is to use gitblame api however I am not able to find any api for it.  Please help me out if you are aware about git blame or similar api. If you have other ideas to solve this problem please share that as well.
